# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app

Problema en Xcode10 me sale este error, cómo solucionarlo????

thread 1 queue com.apple.main-thread (serial)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cuando sale ese error es por que, el compilador intenta acceder a algo pero no lo encuentra, checa si tienes bien conectado tus objetos y si los tienes bien al darles el valor en caso que sean optionals, los estas desempaquetando de manera segura, usando if let o guard let, algunos dato que te haga falta, con un breackpoint tal vez puedas ver que dato es el que te esta sacando el error.

Comment: Lo más seguro es que tengas algún error en tu storyboard. Comprueba que los elementos que estás usando en tu Controller del storyboard están bien relacionados o no hayas borrado nada. Click derecho al simbolo amarillo del View podrás ver tus outlets! Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: y no interesa el pantalla, interesa el texto que aparece en el cuadro del debut. Ahí te dice que es lo que no ha encontrado y porque falla